# Cordova plugman with new plugin names

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, plugman

According to [this announcement](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html) from Cordova, we should start using new plugin IDs (e.g. cordova-plugin-* instead of org.apache.cordova.*).

However, I don't use the Cordova CLI, and I install my plugins manually using plugman.

In that situation, how do we make sure we're using the right plugins? If I try to install something like `--plugin cordova-plugin-device` instead of `--plugin org.apache.cordova.device`, it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

As cordova is now switching over to npm you can find the plugin you are looking for by going to. [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/). And typing cordova-plugins- in the search bar hit search and it will list all available plugins. so [NPM cordova-plugin-device](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-device).

Now im not 100% sure on plugman but it is seriously easy to add new plugins via cordova cli.

if you cd to your project through your terminal all you need to type in is
 `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device`.

And it will add. You can even add straight from github if you'd prefer 
`cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device.git`.

Hope it helps

Comment: See above -- I can't use these commands, since I'm not using Cordova CLI. See [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview) under "Development Paths" and [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html#Using%20Plugman%20to%20Manage%20Plugins).